# How can I 'validate' that an XML file is correctly using the .xsd file I set for it?

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I'm new to XML validation using .xsd files.

Maybe I'm not even asking the correct question here; but is there a way for the computer to tell me that 'Yeah, your XML file is correctly formatted according this .xsd file you made'.

I imagine I need a validator of some sort. Do those exist and it that what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there are several ways:

- your IDE probably has the
  capabilities built-in;
- there is a variety of command line
  tools which will do this;
- there are on-line services for this;

Tell us the details of your development set up and SO will provide more apposite help.  Linux or Windows ?  NetBeans, Visual Studio or Eclipse ?  And so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll be using XML while learning WCF. I'm new to both, but right now we're learning about .xsd validation. I guess I will be using Visual Studio 2008. Does that have the capabilities for validation?

Comment: @Sergio: sadly you picked an IDE I know very little about.  What does the product's documentation say ?  Google ?  Failing that, revise your question.